# React PDFDownloadLink - call onclick event through code explicitly

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation

PDFDownloadLink from react-pdf library downloads a pdf when someone clicks on it.
I want to trigger this click event via code based on some condition .
How do I explicitly invoke the click of PDFDownloadLink through code?

Comment: Which library do you use to generate the pdf? Is that 'react-pdf'?

Comment: @Dushan Randhika: yes I am using react-pdf/renderer library

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but you can pass a `ref` to the render function's return value and use it to call `click()` on imperatively. For that to work you need to use a separate component wrapper:

```
const DownloadLink = memo(function () {
  const linkRef = useRef(null)

  const onLoadingFinished = useCallback(function () {
    // When this function is called the first time it is safe to initiate the download
    const elem = linkRef?.current
    if (elem !== null) {
      elem.click()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc />} fileName={'my-file.pdf'}>
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (
        // You shouldn't call setState() here, so we need to use a separate component to keep track of whether the document has finished rendering
        <WorkaroundContainer ref={linkRef} loading={loading} onLoadingFinished={onLoadingFinished} />
      )}
    </PDFDownloadLink>
  )
})

const WorkaroundContainer = forwardRef(function ({ loading, onLoadingFinished }, ref) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      onLoadingFinished()
    }
  }, [loading])

  // If you only want to initiate the download imperatively, hide the element via CSS (e.g. `visibility: hidden`)
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Download PDF'}
    </div>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<PDFDownloadLink document={< yourPDFComponent/>}>
    // the download button has to be hidden
    <p ref={downloadRef} className={"hidden"}>Download buttton</p>
</PDFDownloadLink>


// inside the function you want to call the event, just call the click like this:
downloadRef.current.click()  // your file will be downloaded, bye
```

Answer (score 0):

So I digged a bit deeper in the source code, as I was actually having the same issue. I mean I needed to perform some action when I get the downloaded file. The onClick also sends `event: MouseEvent` and `instance: ReactPDF.BlobProviderParams`

so you can have a function like that

```js
  const generatePdfSuccess = (
    event: MouseEvent,
    instance: ReactPDF.BlobProviderParams
  ) => {
    if (instance.loading || !instance.url) {
      return;
    }
    downloadURI(instance.url, `filename.pdf`);
    closeModal();
    // or anything else you want to happen after download
  };
```

and because onClick would prevent the regular download from the library you can use function like the below to download this file with your code

```js
function downloadURI(uri: string, name: string) {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = uri;
  link.download = name;
  link.click();
}
```

so with this setup you will use `PDFDownloadLink` as below

```js
<PDFDownloadLink
  className="px-6 py-4"
  fileName={`filename.pdf`}
  onClick={generatePdfSuccess}
  document={<YourPDFDocument/>}
>
  <div>download pdf</div>
</PDFDownloadLink>
```

hope it helps